# expand form elements html

Tags: html

I have a `div` called `main` which is `100% width` of his parent width. 
In `#main` I have `input` field and `textarea`.

I can expand `input` field (width:100%) but how to do the same with `textarea` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the width attribute. Use css instead. You can put the style in a separate css file:

```
input, textarea { width: 100%; }
```

or you can put the style inline in the elements:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 100%" />
<textarea style="width: 100%"></textarea>
```

I recommend the first option because it allows you to separate the style of the page.

Comment: True, here is test case for anyone who want to see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/U98rQ/ :)

Answer (score 2):

This will solve it

```
<div style='width:100%'>
    <input type="text" style='width:100%' />
    <textarea style='width:100%'>Text Area!</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to do it by using the attribute "width".
You can do it quite easy by using css.
Here's an example:

```
<div id="main">
<input name="test" style="width: 100%;"><br/>
<textarea name="bla" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my undestanding u can mention number of rows and columns in the textarea i.e.

```
<textarea name="foo" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
```

or using CSS u can specify a class to it and then mention the style's u want in ur textarea.

In ur HTML file write this:

```
<textarea class="foo"></textarea>
```

and in ur CSS file write this:

```
foo{
   width : 100%; or 100px;
   bockground-color : red; #its upto ur wish.
}
```

You can use either of the two ways